# Numpy reductions over successive non-contiguous slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, vectorization

Say I have two numpy arrays, `A` of shape `(d, f)` and `I` of shape `(d,)` containing indices in `0..n`, e.g.

```
I = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1])
A = np.arange(12).reshape(6, 2)
```

I am looking for a fast way to make reductions, in particular `sum`, `mean` and `max`, over all the slices `A[I == i, :]`; a slow version would be

```
results = np.zeros((I.max() + 1, A.shape[1]))
for i in np.unique(I):
    results[i, :] = np.mean(A[I == i, :], axis=0)
```

which gives in this case

```
results = [[ 2.66666667,  3.66666667],
           [ 7.        ,  8.        ],
           [ 8.        ,  9.        ]])
```

---

**EDIT**: I did some timings based on Divakar's answer and a previous poster's (deleted) `pandas`-based answer.

*Timing code:*

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from time import time

np.random.seed(0)
d = 500000
f = 500
n = 500
I = np.hstack((np.arange(n), np.random.randint(n, size=(d - n,))))
np.random.shuffle(I)
A = np.random.rand(d, f)

def reduce_naive(A, I, op="avg"):
    target_dtype = (np.float if op=="avg" else A.dtype)
    results = np.zeros((I.max() + 1, A.shape[1]), dtype=target_dtype)
    npop = {"avg": np.mean, "sum": np.sum, "max": np.max}.get(op)
    for i in np.unique(I):
        results[i, :] = npop(A[I == i, :], axis=0)
    return results

def reduce_reduceat(A, I, op="avg"):
    sidx = I.argsort()
    sI = I[sidx]
    sortedA = A[sidx]
    idx = np.r_[ 0, np.flatnonzero(sI[1:] != sI[:-1])+1 ]
    if op == "max":
        return np.maximum.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)
    sums = np.add.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)
    if op == "sum":
        return sums
    if op == "avg":
        count = np.r_[idx[1:] - idx[:-1], A.shape[0] - idx[-1]]
        return sums/count.astype(float)[:,None]

def reduce_bincount(A, I, op="avg"):
    ids = (I[:,None] + (I.max()+1)*np.arange(A.shape[1])).ravel()
    sums = np.bincount(ids, A.ravel()).reshape(A.shape[1],-1).T
    if op == "sum":
        return sums
    if op == "avg":
        return sums/np.bincount(ids).reshape(A.shape[1],-1).T

def reduce_pandas(A, I, op="avg"):
    group = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(A), pd.DataFrame(I, columns=("i",))
                     ], axis=1
                    ).groupby('i')
    if op == "sum":
        return group.sum().values
    if op == "avg":
        return group.mean().values
    if op == "max":
        return group.max().values

def reduce_hybrid(A, I, op="avg"):
    sidx = I.argsort()
    sI = I[sidx]
    sortedA = A[sidx]

    idx = np.r_[ 0, np.flatnonzero(sI[1:] != sI[:-1])+1 ]
    unq_sI = sI[idx]    

    m = I.max()+1
    N = A.shape[1]

    target_dtype = (np.float if op=="avg" else A.dtype)
    out = np.zeros((m,N),dtype=target_dtype)
    ss_idx = np.r_[idx,A.shape[0]]

    npop = {"avg": np.mean, "sum": np.sum, "max": np.max}.get(op)
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        out[unq_sI[i]] = npop(sortedA[ss_idx[i]:ss_idx[i+1]], axis=0)
    return out

for op in ("sum", "avg", "max"):
    for name, method in (("naive   ", reduce_naive), 
                         ("reduceat", reduce_reduceat),
                         ("pandas  ", reduce_pandas),
                         ("bincount", reduce_bincount),
                         ("hybrid  ", reduce_hybrid)
                         ("numba   ", reduce_numba)
                        ):    
        if op == "max" and name == "bincount":
            continue
        # if name is not "naive":
        #      assert np.allclose(method(A, I, op), reduce_naive(A, I, op))
        times = []
        for tries in range(3):
            time0 = time(); method(A, I, op)
            times.append(time() - time0); 
        print(name, op, "{:.2f}".format(np.min(times)))
    print()
```

*Timings*:

```
naive    sum 1.10
reduceat sum 4.62
pandas   sum 5.29
bincount sum 1.54
hybrid   sum 0.62
numba    sum 0.31

naive    avg 1.12
reduceat avg 4.45
pandas   avg 5.23
bincount avg 2.43
hybrid   avg 0.61
numba    avg 0.33

naive    max 1.19
reduceat max 3.18
pandas   max 5.24
hybrid   max 0.72
numba    max 0.34
```

(I chose `d` and `n` as typical values for my use case - I have added the code for numba-versions in my answer).

Comment: Your `pandas` times look low (compared to my tests), but that's because you've taken the data frame creation and `groupby` out of the time loop.

Comment: @hpaulj note that the `groupby` is inside the function, so inside of the time loop. I have updated the timings, fixed the seed and taken best of 3 for better reproducibility. I have pandas `0.19.2`.

Comment: I accepted Divakar's solution as a pure-numpy approach, but this shows compiled code with numba or cython should give the fastest solutions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1 : Using NumPy ufunc reduceat**

We have [`ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) for those three reduction operations and luckily we also have  [`ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to perform those reductions limited at particular intervals along an axis. So, using those, we would have those three operations computed like so -

```
# Gives us sorted array based on input indices I and indices at which the
# sorted array should be interval-limited for reduceat operations to be
# applied later on using those results
def sorted_array_intervals(A, I):
    # Compute sort indices for I. To be later used for sorting A based on it.
    sidx = I.argsort()
    sI = I[sidx]
    sortedA = A[sidx]

    # Get indices at which intervals change. Also, get count in each interval
    idx = np.r_[ 0, np.flatnonzero(sI[1:] != sI[:-1])+1 ]
    return sortedA, idx

# Groupby sum reduction using the interval indices 
# to perform interval-limited ufunc reductions
def groupby_sum(A, I):
    sortedA, idx = sorted_array_intervals(A,I)
    return np.add.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)

# Groupby mean reduction
def groupby_mean(A, I):
    sortedA, idx = sorted_array_intervals(A,I)
    sums = np.add.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)
    count = np.r_[idx[1:] - idx[:-1], A.shape[0] - idx[-1]]
    return sums/count.astype(float)[:,None]

# Groupby max reduction
def groupby_max(A, I):
    sortedA, idx = sorted_array_intervals(A,I)
    return np.maximum.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)
```

Thus, if we need all those operations, we could reuse with one instance of `sorted_array_intervals`, like so -

```
def groupby_sum_mean_max(A, I):
    sortedA, idx = sorted_array_intervals(A,I)
    sums = np.add.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)
    count = np.r_[idx[1:] - idx[:-1], A.shape[0] - idx[-1]]
    avgs = sums/count.astype(float)[:,None]
    maxs = np.maximum.reduceat(sortedA, idx, axis=0)
    return sums, avgs, maxs
```

**Approach #1-B : Hybrid version (sort + slice + reduce)**

Here's a hybrid version that does takes help from `sorted_array_intervals` to get the sorted array and the indices at which the intervals change into the next group, but at the last stage uses slicing to sum each interval and does this iteratively for each of the groups. The slicing helps here as we are working with `views`.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
def reduce_hybrid(A, I, op="avg"):
    sidx = I.argsort()
    sI = I[sidx]
    sortedA = A[sidx]

    # Get indices at which intervals change. Also, get count in each interval
    idx = np.r_[ 0, np.flatnonzero(sI[1:] != sI[:-1])+1 ]
    unq_sI = sI[idx]    

    m = I.max()+1
    N = A.shape[1]

    target_dtype = (np.float if op=="avg" else A.dtype)
    out = np.zeros((m,N),dtype=target_dtype)
    ss_idx = np.r_[idx,A.shape[0]]

    npop = {"avg": np.mean, "sum": np.sum, "max": np.max}.get(op)
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        out[unq_sI[i]] = npop(sortedA[ss_idx[i]:ss_idx[i+1]], axis=0)
    return out
```

Runtime test (Using the setup from the benchmarks posted in the question) -

```
In [432]: d = 500000
     ...: f = 500
     ...: n = 500
     ...: I = np.hstack((np.arange(n), np.random.randint(n, size=(d - n,))))
     ...: np.random.shuffle(I)
     ...: A = np.random.rand(d, f)
     ...: 

In [433]: %timeit reduce_naive(A, I, op="sum")
     ...: %timeit reduce_hybrid(A, I, op="sum")
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 549 ms per loop

In [434]: %timeit reduce_naive(A, I, op="avg")
     ...: %timeit reduce_hybrid(A, I, op="avg")
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 550 ms per loop

In [435]: %timeit reduce_naive(A, I, op="max")
     ...: %timeit reduce_hybrid(A, I, op="max")
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 631 ms per loop
```

---

**Approach #2 : Using NumPy bincount**

Here's another approach using [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) that does bin-based summing. So, with it, we could compute the sum and average values and also avoid sorting in the process, like so -

```
ids = (I[:,None] + (I.max()+1)*np.arange(A.shape[1])).ravel()
sums = np.bincount(ids, A.ravel()).reshape(A.shape[1],-1).T
avgs = sums/np.bincount(ids).reshape(A.shape[1],-1).T
```

Comment: Great work, I had noticed reduceat but had discarded it because it only operated on contiguous intervals

Comment: You could also use, `_,idx,count=np.unique(sI,return_counts=True,return_index=True)`.  Even though it does a sort,  it's actually a bit faster than your `r_` expressions.

Comment: Based on apparently defavorable timings for the sort-based methods I chose to reopen the question for now.

Comment: @Maxim Please check out the just added `Hybrid version`. Seems to be `2x` better.

Comment: Good find @Divakar, I will leave the question open a bit longer but it seems already some good improvement for a pure numpy-based version

Answer (score 2):

Using the python/numpy jit compiler [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) I was able to get shorter timings with just-in-time compilation of the intuitive linear algorithm:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def reducenb_avg(A, I):
    d, f = A.shape
    n = I.max() + 1
    result = np.zeros((n, f), np.float)
    count = np.zeros((n, 1), int)
    for i in range(d):
        result[I[i], :] += A[i]
        count[I[i], 0] += 1
    return result/count

@jit
def reducenb_sum(A, I):
    d, f = A.shape
    n = I.max() + 1
    result = np.zeros((n, f), A.dtype)
    for i in range(d):
        result[I[i], :] += A[i]
    return result

@jit
def reducenb_max(A, I):
    d, f = A.shape
    n = I.max() + 1
    result = -np.inf * np.ones((n, f))
    count = np.zeros((n, f))
    for i in range(d):
        result[I[i], :] = np.maximum(A[i], result[I[i], :])
    return result

def reduce_numba(A, I, op="avg"):
    return {"sum": reducenb_sum, "avg": reducenb_avg, "max": reducenb_max}.get(op)(A, I)
```

On the benchmark problem, these finish in ~0.32s, about half of the time of pure numpy sorting-based methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that can be used for this is the unbuffered `add.at`:

```
def add_at(I,A):
    n = I.max() + 1
    res = np.zeros((n,A.shape[1]))
    cnt = np.zeros((n,1))
    np.add.at(res, I, A)
    np.add.at(cnt, I, 1)
    return res/cnt
```

(It's quite close in structure the `numba` `reducenb_avg`)

```
In [438]: add_at(I,A)
Out[438]: 
array([[ 2.66666667,  3.66666667],
       [ 7.        ,  8.        ],
       [ 8.        ,  9.        ]])
```

For this small problem it tests well, compared to others, but it does not scale well (going from 3x faster to 12x slower).